# Angular material: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use the Datepicker component in Angular Material. Here is my HTML code:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" disabled>
<mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
```

However, it's not working for me and I'm getting the following error:

> Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter.

The error message tells me that I need to import MatNativeDateModule as well as MatDatepickerModule but I have done that. Here is my import code below from app.module.ts:

```
import {
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
} from '@angular/material';
```

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You need to import both **`MatDatepickerModule`**  and **`MatNativeDateModule`** under imports and add  **`MatDatepickerModule`** under providers

```
 imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule 
  ],
  providers: [  
    MatDatepickerModule,  
  ],
```

Comment: The Md prefix is deprecated. Please provide solutions using Mat syntax.

Comment: In my case, I also needed to import them from the API with 
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/';

Comment: this works thank you! but what if we using separate file to import material? can we set providers there? I'm new to this!

Comment: Thank you I just add MatNativeDateModule import from core and thats works

Comment: I don't think Modules belong in the providers array.  Just adding to imports should be sufficient

Comment: No sir, this is not working

Answer (score 83):

**Angular 8, 9**

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
```

**Angular 7 and below**

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
```

You need to import both `MatDatepickerModule` and `MatNativeDateModule` under imports and add `MatDatepickerModule` under providers

```
imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule 
  ],
  providers: [  
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule  
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks this helped for Angular 9. BTW import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material'; works for 8

Comment: Why you need to add them to the providers array?

Comment: if not you have to inject each component wise

Comment: @lilansilva can you elaborate?  My test works without adding to the providers but maybe i'm doing something out of habit that I don't need to be doing

Answer (score 18):

Just import the

> MatNativeDateModule

along with the

> MatDatepickerModule

at the app.module.ts or app-routing.module.ts.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule 
]
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Official docs: [Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter/MAT_DATE_FORMATS](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#error-matdatepicker-no-provider-found-for-dateadapter-mat_date_formats)

> The datepicker was built to be date implementation agnostic. This means that it can be made to work with a variety of different date implementations. However it also means that developers need to make sure to provide the appropriate pieces for the datepicker to work with their chosen implementation. The easiest way to ensure this is just to import one of the pre-made modules: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule.

Fix:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

Comment: According to the docs: `We highly recommend using the MomentDateAdapter or a custom DateAdapter that works with the formatting/parsing library of your choice.` Since `MatNativeDateModule is based off of the functionality available in JavaScript's native Date object, and is thus not suitable for many locales. One of the biggest shortcomings of the native Date object is the inability to set the parse format.`

Answer (score 5):

**In contrast** on what has been said previously by some colleagues, you should NOT put MatDatepickerModule in prodivers array unless you have a good reason for it.

As a reminder (https://angular.io/guide/providers), and as it is well explained in the official documentation: A provider is an instruction to the Dependency Injection system on how to obtain a value for a dependency. Most of the time, these dependencies are services that you create and provide. In addition to this, providers are available to all the classes in the application which is not i guess, the purpose of MatDatepickerModule ! (since you should use it just in some few components)

So all what you need is to follow of course the examples well documented in the Angular official website (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

But before to check the solution, let's have a look at the self-explanatory error message:

```
ERROR Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, ....
```

It is not because the error talks initially about **provider**, that you just need to inject the staff in provider. Continue reading the full error...

Just one word about **DateAdapter**: DateAdapter is a class which adapts an object to be usable as a date by cdk-based components that work with dates. This DateAdapter needs to use some native functions from MatNativeDateModule

The suggested solution is:

In your app.module.ts import both MatDatepickerModule and MatNativeDateModule

```
...
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the MatNativeDateModule together with  MatDatepicker or MatCalendar inside your "sub module" (when you create your own module inside main app) you might need to import the MatNativeDateModule inside your main *app module*. Without this I was still getting

```
core.js?4dd3:1673 ERROR Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.
    at createMissingDateImplError (datepicker.es5.js?d462:38:1)
    at new MatCalendar (datepicker.es5.js?d462:1563:1)
```

Please not what the message is saying "at your application root".

My "submodule" delaration was looking like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        (...)
        MatDatepickerModule
    ],
    providers: [MatDatepickerModule],
})
export class MySubModule
```

Adding MatNativeDateModule to above submodule delaration was not helping. I was getting another error:

```
core.js?4dd3:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DexGridCalendarCellEditorModule'
Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DexGridCalendarCellEditorModule'
    at syntaxError (compiler.js?db2b:1021:1)
    at eval (compiler.js?db2b:10589:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js?db2b:10558:1)
```

Finally when I added the import to main app module it started working correctly:

```
// NOTE: see the import below 
import { MatNativeDateModule } from "@angular/material/";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatNativeDateModule
    ],
})
export class AppModule {
```

Comment: I can confirm I had the same issue and came up with same solution. As a small clarification: you don't need to add MatDatepickerModule into providers array. Providing to imports is enough and also providing either MatNativeDateModule or MatMomentDateModule to AppModule is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

### Angular 17

[Dimitry's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77681812/12376352) answer works well with **Angular 17** onwards and standalone components. In `main.ts` provide the following:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule), // here
  ],
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. I can also import the module in a specific standalone component.

import {provideNativeDateAdapter} from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  providers: [provideNativeDateAdapter()],
})