# MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have imported the matdatepicker in my app.module.ts file but still it shows some error. I can't get the material component working. the button works fine and uses angular material component. But when I use datepicker it doesn't work.

app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import{ HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { InactiveusersComponent } from './component/inactiveusers/inactiveusers.component';
import { CalendarComponent } from './component/calendar/calendar.component';
import { InactiveItemComponent } from './component/inactive-item/inactive-item.component';
import { NewtableComponent } from './component/newtable/newtable.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    InactiveusersComponent,
    CalendarComponent,
    InactiveItemComponent,
    NewtableComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  exports:[
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [MatFormFieldModule,MatDatepickerModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

calendar.component.html

```
<input #startDate  type="date" name="startdate">
<input #endDate type="date"name="enddate">

<button (click)="sendRange(startDate.value,endDate.value)" mat-button color="primary">Submit</button>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

ERROR Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.
    at createMissingDateImplError (datepicker.js:37)
    at new MatDatepickerInput (datepicker.js:2344)
    at createClass (core.js:24577)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:24386)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:34994)
    at callViewAction (core.js:35444)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:35349)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:35023)
    at callViewAction (core.js:35444)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:35349)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular material: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720908/angular-material-matdatepicker-no-provider-found-for-dateadapter)

Comment: I have also added module in the provider. As you see. But still the same problem.

Comment: you didn't import MatNativeDateModule.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I've solved it by adding follow modules:

```
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';
import { MatMomentDateModule } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
```

and in your imports

```
imports: [
    ...
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule,
  ],
```

I'm not that deep in material-angular I've only follow the error message advice

> ERROR Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You
> must import one of the following modules at your application root:
> MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom
> implementation.

**Attention**: For newer Angular versions you only need to import one module:

```
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';

...
    imports: [
        ...
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
      ],
```

instead:

```
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';
import { MatMomentDateModule } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
...
imports: [
    ...
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule,
  ],
```

Comment: I guess the API change since this was posted, now it's - import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';

Comment: I guess they messed it up again. I imported both and still get the error in version 9.1.2... You need to add them in app module now rather than the imported modules... :/ proper documentation can help... right?

Answer (score 63):

I got, Here working fine Just import the modules in APP.MODULE.TS file

```
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
imports: [

...

MatNativeDateModule 
],
```

Comment: Thanks, `from @angular/material` not work but `'@angular/material/core'` did .

Answer (score 9):

I got, Here working fine
Just import the modules in APP.MODULE.TS file

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

imports: [
MatDatepickerModule
,MatNativeDateModule,MatInputModule
]

HTML :
You need to wrap element with

Tag
<form>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 7):

The imports have changed. Use this instead:

```
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
```

Answer (score 6):

I just used the first import referred:

```
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';
```

the other import got me to another error I didn't solved, but it wasn't necessary.

Don't forget to add MatNativeDateModule to the imports array in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
 
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
```

This is working fine work me

Answer (score 2):

**Angular 17**

I solved the problem by adding the provider `importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule)` to `app.config.ts`

Full code:

```
import {ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom} from '@angular/core';
import {provideRouter} from '@angular/router';

import {routes} from './app.routes';
import {provideAnimations} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {provideHttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {MatNativeDateModule} from "@angular/material/core";

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule)//here
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and it was resolved by only adding the following import in my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';

imports: [
MatNativeDateModule

]