# Material Datepicker is not working in modal/popup in angular 11

Tags: typescript, angular-material, uidatepicker, angular11

Although I have used
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
These are the errors:

```
ERROR Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.
    at createMissingDateImplError (datepicker.js:160)
    at new MatDatepickerInputBase (datepicker.js:3031)
    at new MatDatepickerInput (datepicker.js:3283)
```

Comment: you need to import `NativeDateAdapter` as well in your module

Comment: Did you check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503946/matdatepicker-no-provider-found-for-dateadapter-you-must-import-one-of-the-fol

Comment: Also after importing in file, you also imported it in NgModule imports array, right?